# Newly created sites get old Content Type templates

Tags: content-type, document-template, content-type-hub

We moved from _cts templates to a centrally stored template in _layouts some time ago but noticed recently that newly created site, for example with using New-SPSite, gets old content type templates in the ResourceFolder. The DocumentTemplateUrl is correctly assigned but many old versions of the template are stored in _cts/ContentTypeName.

I have cleared all old files out from _cts but still when a new site is created the files appear in the new site. Where do these files come from and how can I get rid of this behaviour?

The content types and _layout template is working fine but the clients environment got hundreds of content types so the footprint of each site is huge due to all the old templates. We are taking hundreds of files in the recycle bin of a newly created site.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I can think of:

1. You have a some sort of feature stapling going on.  You need to
   ensure no existing features are being activated with that are
   deploying these templates.
2. Check that the site template itself has not been modified to include
       these content types.

Also - this is just a reach on my part, make sure the content types are deleted completely (from the Recycle bin as well).

Comment: Thanks for at least having a thing about it. Unfortunately there are no features being activated on these new sites nor do we have any features like that. All the templates are old templates from the Content type hub. The site templates are all default too.

I have cleaned all folders and all bins from the whole test environment but these are still coming back. Wonder if the content type sync job saves templates in some other db other than the content db.

Comment: Are you enabling Content Type Sync on these new collections?  What happens if you don't, do you still get these?